# Model Cell Culture (HeLa)

Tags: modeling, procedural

I'd like to procedurally model a cell culture of, e.g., HeLa cells, as if they were observed through a light-microscope. See the following image for reference:

[image: https://www.microscopyu.com/assets/gallery-images/Comparison/DIC_heladic.jpg]

I want to use the images for machine-learning training, where I want to create a model that learns an instance-segmentation of the cells. So what I need is a way of procedurally generating large number of images with such cells, with randomized number, shape and density of cells. And then I also need a way to retrieve (or render out) an instance mask, where each instance has a different color.

I guess starting with a voronoi shader would be a way. But the resulting cells are too "low-poly". If they were of geometry, I would add a subdivision to smooth them out, but how to do that in a shader?
Or should I do it all in geometry-nodes?

Any hint would be good! I am quite experienced with blender in general, just have never really done anything procedural so far :(

Cheers!

Comment: Great! Can you please explain one thing? What do you exactly mean by low-poly? I'm quite sure the solution is simply to use an RGB curves node in blender.

Comment: When creating a voronoi map, the individual instances have sharp corners, each instance consists of about 3 - 5 faces. If you look on the cell image above, you see that some sort of bevelling / smoothing would be required, to have smooth cell outlines.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of that low poly voronoi?

Comment: You can see plenty of examples here on the blender documentation page:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/voronoi.html
And indeed, at the very end, there's an example of how a bevelled voronoi can be achieved :D

Comment: So, that solves your problem, right?